# Unable to configure SQS queue notification in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I created an SQS queue and added policy under permission tab allowing only my account users to configure the configure the notification

Policy Document

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:sqsqueue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid111111111111",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "111111111111"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:queue"
    }
  ]
```

Navigate to S3 and try to configure event notification for the above queue, it is throwing an error

> Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Permissions on the destination queue do not allow S3 to publish
>   notifications from this bucket.
>   (arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:queue)*

am I doing something wrong? Can someone help me please

Comment: Might be relevant: [SQS Policy to allow an S3 bucket to publish messages](https://gist.github.com/marcelog/7b0224b63c90802996ab2dee7d7082e4)

Comment: I followed this document as well - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-creating-custom-policies-access-policy-examples.html. But no luck :(

Comment: This AWS help page is for the same thing but using SNS:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/
I still haven't managed to get it working yet but I'm pretty sure the page holds the key as the template provided works for SNS.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. No way to configure notifications without making the queue world-accessible, which isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
in the Principal tag.

Here the policy document

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:sqsqueue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid111111111111",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:queue"
    }
  ]
```

This is explained in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173251

Comment: OMFG i spent hours on this; adding `Service` for the principal (instead of `AWS` with a catch-all) resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This template file creates a bucket, SQS Queue and a policy to connect the two:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  IncomingBucketName:
    Type: 'String'
    Description: 'Incoming Bucket Name'
    Default: 'some-bucket-name-here'
Resources:
  IncomingFileQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties: {}
  SQSQueuePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: 'MyQueuePolicy'
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: 'Statement-id'
            Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              AWS: "*"
            Action: 'sqs:SendMessage'
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [ IncomingFileQueue, Arn ]
      Queues:
        - Ref: IncomingFileQueue
  IncomingFileBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    DependsOn:
      - SQSQueuePolicy
      - IncomingFileQueue
    Properties:
      AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl
      BucketName:
        Ref: IncomingBucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        QueueConfigurations:
          - Event:
              s3:ObjectCreated:Put
            Queue:
              Fn::GetAtt: [ IncomingFileQueue, Arn ]
```

I was getting the same issue but used this page to work out how to connect the three resources in order to successfully deploy the stack:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/

I'm still working on the Policy Condition as the form recommended in the above link doesn't work for SQS. That being the case, the above template is not secure and shouldn't be used in production as it allows anyone to add messages to the queue.

I'll update this answer once I've figured that bit out...